# How to preprocess html templates in app built on the quasar framework

Tags: vite, rollup, quasar

My future web app is a part of the firmware. The firmware is supposed to be built for a lot of devices. For each of them there is a profile with configuration parameters. I need to clean up app's html templates from unnecessary features. The reason i want to do it at build time is the size of firmware. So, i want to replace all `v-if` statements that use `profile` object with constant values.
For example, this html

```
<div v-if="profile.feature1"></div>
```

is supposed to be replaced with this:

```
<div v-if="false"></div>
```

After this the whole div tag will be removed as dead.
As far as I understand, I can do a similar thing with js by writing a plugin for `rollup`, but with html... no idea.

In previous version of this web app i used `gulp` plugin as a part of html processing pipeline.

Which options do i have if i migrate to quasar?

I googled the subject but with no success.

PS:
I figured out that i have no need to write `rollup` plugin in case of js.
According to docs:

> When compiling your website/app, if () branches depending on process.env are evaluated, and if the expression is false, they get stripped out of the file.

That's a good news. But i still don't know how to access `process.env` in templates and would it be stripped like js.

#### Update:

I found another way to preprocess sources. There is `rawDefine` property in `quasar.config.js`. AFAIK it's based on the same `define` `vite`'s feature. It's allows me to use `SOME_FEATURE`  constants in source code directly without `process.env`. It didn't give the answer for templates by itself, but i looked at what came to `define` plugin as input and saw `_ctx.SOME_FEATURE`. So, now i can add `_ctx.` prefixed version of every constant in `rawDefine` to make it replaced by `define` plugin.

The problems that i still have:

1. I don't know how reliable it is. It looks like a workaround.
2. The tag with `v-if="SOME_FEATURE"` is stripped, but if the tag refers to a component and that component isn't used anywhere else it's still here. On other hand, if i replace `v-if="SOME_FEATURE"` to `v-if="false"` then both (the tag of the component and the component itself) are removed.

Comment: You could just give `profile.feature1` a default value of false. You can check with your browser developer tools that the HTML inside is not there.

Comment: Yes. In the browser it won't be there, but i need it not to be there in the bundle. In other words I talk about the tree shaking.

Comment: Oh right it's meant as a dynamic tree shaking. Maybe [check if dynamic component exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69897185/check-if-dynamic-component-exists)?

Comment: Dynamic components are not the choice in my case, unfortunately. I have a whole lot of small features (usually turning into several fields on a page) which originated from small differences in devices (for instance now we have about 300 profile constants) and customer's requirements as well. Though each separate difference is small, as a rule, but altogether they end up taking considerable space on the flash.